# in Vue, Why key duplication occurs when if and for are on a label？

Tags: vue.js, duplicates, key

The following code will report an error：key duplication

```
<option-group
    v-if="dataSource[0] && dataSource[0].options"
    v-for="item in dataSource"
    :key="item.label"
    :label="item.label"
>
...
</option-group>
<Option
    v-else
    v-for="option in dataSource"
    :label="option.label"
    :value="option.value"
    :key="option.value"
></Option>
```

but following code will not report the error, when I wrap the code with 'template' label:

```
<template v-if="dataSource[0] && dataSource[0].options">
    <option-group
        v-for="item in dataSource"
        :key="item.label"
        :label="item.label"
    >
    ...
    </option-group>
</template>
<template v-else>
    <Option
        v-for="option in dataSource"
        :label="option.label"
        :value="option.value"
        :key="option.value"
    ></Option>
</template>
```

I want to know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in your first example both the `option-group` and `Option` components are rendered thus same key is in two different elements, one in `option-group` and one in `Option`.

Both are rendered because you used `v-for` and `v-if` at the same time. It is not recommended because

> VueJS prioritizes the v-for directive over the v-if directive. So under the hood, it loops through every element and THEN checks the v-if conditional.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.codechief.org/article/dont-use-v-if-with-v-for-elements)